# Can I install phpize7.1 to Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: php, ubuntu, php-7.1, ubuntu-15.10, phpize

I have old Ubuntu 15.10 which unsupported anymore. I need php7, but I can not update it to Ubuntu 16/18. I installed php7.1 from source, but also I need phpize to compile extensions. Is it possible to install phpize from source (like I did it for php7.1) ?

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php7 \
--with-readline \
--with-config-file-path=/etc/php7/apache2 \
--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php7/apache2/conf.d \
--enable-mbstring \
--enable-zip \
--enable-bcmath \
--enable-pcntl \
--enable-ftp \
--enable-exif \
--enable-calendar \
--enable-sysvmsg \
--enable-sysvsem \
--enable-sysvshm \
--enable-wddx \
--enable-intl \
--with-curl \
--with-mcrypt \
--with-iconv \
--with-gmp \
--with-pspell \
--with-gd \
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
--with-png-dir=/usr \
--with-zlib-dir=/usr \
--with-xpm-dir=/usr \
--with-freetype-dir=/usr \
--with-t1lib=/usr \
--enable-gd-native-ttf \
--enable-gd-jis-conv \
--with-openssl \
--with-gettext=/usr \
--with-zlib=/usr \
--with-bz2 \
--with-recode=/usr \
--with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs \
--with-ldap \
--with-xdebug \
--with-pdo-pgsql
```

Comment: show `configure ` parameters when compile

Comment: @FAEWZX added configure

Comment: `/usr/local/php7/bin/phpize`